# How to scroll the page with javascript before body load?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to scroll the page 50px before body load. But it always waits for body load before running the code.

I'm not quite sure what's the reason, I seem to remember  running as they are parsed.

I tried with both, jquery and plain javascript, this is my code:

```
$(document).scrollTop('50');
window.scrollBy(0,50);
```

How do I make it work before body load?

Comment: There is nothing to scroll before the body is parsed and rendered on the screen

Comment: You mean to scroll blank page before any html is loaded?

Comment: you can set the body opacity to 0 then on body loaded execute the scroll and finally set its opacity to 1 so it will be shown already scrolled

Comment: Would CSS work? Body { margin-top:-50px}

Comment: It's not clear why you should scroll the page 50px before the body is load, so a proper answer is hard to give. The scroll took in account two things:  the size of the document, and the size of the window. So, if the size of the document is bigger than the size of the window, you can scroll. But if the body is not loaded, you have no idea if the size exceed. Are you doing that because you're on mobile (e.g. iOS)? If is that the case, there are different approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no body when you are calling the event so nothing would happen
one way around to this is that set the height of body so some constant number
and add onLoad event on the body tag

```
<script>
SomeFunction(){
 //scrollNow
}
</Script>
<body onLoad="SomeFunction()" style="height:500px;"></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found one working solution, maybe somebody will find cleaner one.
This can scroll the page even before the onload:

```js
document.writeln('&nbsp;');
document.body.style.height = '5000px';
$(window).scrollTop(50);
```

[Test script here](http://pastebin.com/KusECR1p).

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Create css offset class and assign to the body

    .offset{
         margin-top:-500px;
        }

    So that body will be loaded with 500px offset from top

    2. Then add following code to the body

        <body class="offset" onLoad="window.scroll(0, 150)">

    3. then using jquery, remove offset class when page is loaded

        $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".row").removeClass("offset");
        });
```

This will work http://www.frameinn.com/thatisuday/about